# Sum of datetime column in sql 05

Tags: sql-server, database, datetime, datetime-format

I have a column named as "total_hours_worked" in my sql table which is of "datetime" datatype
I want to find out the total of "total hours worked in sql server".

How to do this?
I googled but didn't got a practical solution.

Comment: @praveen no i cannot do that because sum function works for integer values.if i try to do what you told i will get an error like this
"Operand data type datetime is invalid for sum operator."

Comment: @SimonWhitehead that doesnt work buddy.. sum is for integers. i want to total the time

Comment: you need two fields or two values to find different between them, then after you can find sum of them only...

Comment: can you post sample data and the result which you want

Answer (score 1):

Something like this if I understand your data correctly.

```
declare @T table
(
  total_hours_worked datetime
)

insert into @T values ('05:30:00')
insert into @T values ('10:00:00')
insert into @T values ('15:00:00')

select sum(datediff(minute, 0, total_hours_worked)) / 60.0 as hours_worked
from @T
```

Result:

```
hours_worked
---------------------------------------
30.500000
```

If you only need to store the hours you should consider an integer datatype instead of `datetime`. It will be more efficient and easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.Here I considered seconds also.

```
declare @T table
(
  total_hours_worked datetime
)

insert into @T values ('05:30:00')
insert into @T values ('10:00:00')
insert into @T values ('15:00:00')
insert into @T values ('05:25:45')

select SUM((DATEPART(hh,total_hours_worked)*60)+DATEPART(mi,total_hours_worked)+(DATEPART(ss,total_hours_worked)/(60.0)))/60.0  as TotalHours from @T
```

Comment: Check the query now,I have updated to work with sql 2005.Initially u did not mention the sql version so i did it in sql 2008.